# How to clean spilled drink from dashboard and control buttons?

Tags: cleaning, interior, dashboard, climate-control

A sports drink was recently spilled over the dashboard and control surfaces (radio, climate control, etc) of our 2011 Chrysler Towne & Country. The drink was immediately cleaned up and no damage occurred to the electronics, but we've got a bunch of buttons that are now stuck and sticking.

What's the best way to go about cleaning those buttons? Can they be popped off like computer keyboard keys?

Answer (score 1):

Wipe it with a towel of soap-water solution as it can take away the sugary content. Once done, you can use a hair dryer with mild temp.